# add a row to a tabale using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[image]   Here's my form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formController.js"></script>
</head>

<body >

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">IRNIA Meditel</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="form_details.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Form_details</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="icons.html"> Icons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Create database</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                           Create Tables
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <form role="form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>id_entity</label>
                                            <input class="form-control">
                                            <p class="help-block">the id is autogenerated</p>
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>entity_name</label>
                                            <input class="form-control">
                                            <p class="help-block">the name of table required</p>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            DataTables Advanced Tables
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="dataTable_wrapper" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="formController">
                                <table   class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>id_field</th>
                                            <th>name</th>
                                            <th>size</th>
                                            <th>type</th>   
                                        </tr>

                                    </thead>
                                   <tbody>

                                   <tr class="table" ng-repeat="bd in bds">

                                            <td> <input type="text" ng-model="bd.id_field" /> </td>
                                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bd.field_name" /></td> 
                                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bd.size" /></td> 
                                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bd.type" /></td>

                                   </tr>  
                                   </tbody>
                                   </table> 
                                     <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addRow()">addRow</button></td><br> 
                                    <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>
```

I want to add a new row to my table using angular js , for that i declare the controller in the div with ng-controller and the model with ng-model , you will find the details below :

Here's the formController.js

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope){
  $scope.bds = [];

  $scope.addRow = function(){
    var  = {
        id_field: $scope.id_field,
         field_name: $scope.field_name,
         size: $scope.size,
         type: $scope.type,
    };

    $scope.bds.push(bd);
  }; 

}
</html>
```

When i try to click into the button addRow ,it doesn't work :/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78313/discussion-on-question-by-chawqi-hajar-add-a-row-to-a-tabale-using-angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if it works.

```
<table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>id_field</th>
                                            <th>name</th>
                                            <th>size</th>
                                            <th>type</th>   
                                        </tr>

                                    </thead>
                                   <tbody>

  <tr class="table" ng-repeat="bd in bds">
  <td> <input type="text" ng-model="bd.id_field" /> </td>
                                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bd.field_name" /></td> 
                                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bd.size" /></td> 
                                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bd.type" /></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addRow()">addRow</button></td>

                                   </tr>  
                                   </tbody>
                                   </table> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addRow()">addRow</button>
```

**FormController.js**

```
 angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('ExampleController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.bds = [];

  $scope.addRow = function() {

     var bd= {
        id_field: $scope.id_field,
         field_name: $scope.field_name,
         size: $scope.size,
         type: $scope.type,
    };
    $scope.bds.push(bd);
  }
}]);
```

Comment: ok let me try again? What's the problem is your controller still not executed? Have u checked adding alert in your controller not function because first you will need to check this and change your controller name it's a file name you have given

Comment: i changed the name of the controller  as you tell me before and i also add alert to verify if ti's excuted but it didn't work ,i still don't know what's  the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add angularjs to your project, add the following line:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
```

And use `console.log('message')` inide your angular code to debug and check if it's working or where it stops working.
Also avoid using jquery with angular, everything you need to do with jquery is doable with angular and easier, plus it is good practice not to mix both of them.

Comment: don't add it at the end of your file.